# Saving data to django database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three django models (`user`, `member (extended user)`, `subscription`) and the are connected with a ForeignKey.

And then when the user want to create a new account I save it to the database as follows:

```
language = Language.objects.get(key="EN")
country = Country.objects.get(key="BE")

user = User()
user.username = form.cleaned_data['email']
user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
user.save()

member = Member()
member.number = form.cleaned_data['member_id']
member.name = '{} {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['firstname'], form.cleaned_data['lastname'])
member.address = form.cleaned_data['address']
member.postcode = form.cleaned_data['postcode']
member.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
member.country = country
member.telephone = form.cleaned_data['telephone']
member.mobile = form.cleaned_data['mobile']
member.user = user
member.language = language
member.active = False
member.save()

subscription = Subscription()
subscription.started = datetime.date.today()
subscription.type = Type.objects.get(default=True)
subscription.member = member
subscription.save()
```

That works fine.

But I want to ask if there is a better way to store it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, maybe you need it
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/